# String replacement in R using stringr for long complicated string

Tags: r, stringr

I have a long string from a SQL query that resembles the below:

```
.*
[FOO] IN (1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678, 6789, etc )
AND [BAR] IN (1,234,123,536,889,465)
.*
```

I basically want to replace the numbers in the `[FOO]` line without affecting anything else.

My desired output would look something like this:

```
.*
[FOO] IN (9876,8765,7654)
AND [BAR] IN (1,234,123,536,889,465)
.*
```

I tried using the `regexp()` with `\\[FOO\\] IN \\(.*\\)` but that grabbed too much.

I also tried using `[0-9]{4}` but didn't know how to handle the commas since the last number doesn't have a comma at the end.

It should be noted that the length is varying, i.e. there can be different numbers of 4 digit codes in the foo line.

Comment: How does your string looks like exactly? and what you want to replace the numbers with? Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Would this work: `sub("\\((.*?)\\)", "(9876,8765,7654)", s)` assuming your string is storing in `s`?

Comment: Yes! Sort of....since this wasn't the first instance of parenthesis this wouldn't exactly work but if I include [FOO] it will. Excellent thank you.